# bottle.py URL routing & reverse howto?

Tags: python, url-routing, bottle

Sample Bottle.py code:

```
@route('/show_<name>')
def show(name):
   return ''
```

My question is:

1. Given a URL, how do we get the view function? E.g. the URL is `/show_magic`, I need to know the `show()` function is responsible for this request URL
2. Given a route (not Router!!) and parameters, how to get the URL? e.g. I need a function called reverse which `reverse(default_app().routes[0], name='me') == '/show_me'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, use [`Bottle.match`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Bottle.match). Given a `path` (i.e. `'/show_magic'`) and the `method` (`GET` or `POST` or whatever), the following will return a tuple containing a `Route` object and its parameters:

```
default_app().match({'PATH_INFO': path, 'REQUEST_METHOD': method})
```

The function called is the `Route` object's [`callback`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Route.callback) or [`call`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Route.call) attribute.

For your second question, use the router's `build` method with the route's `rule` and kwargs:

```
default_app().router.build(route.rule, name='me')
```

That doesn't seem to be documented, but it works.

Comment: thanks, looked at your code and bottle source code, it really does the trick.

Answer (score 6):

you might want to consider named routes

```
@route('/show_<item_name>', name='item_show')
def show(item_name):
   return ''
```

now given the route name and params how to get the URL? we use get_url

```
get_url('item_show', item_name='my_item')
```

http://nongraphical.com/2012/08/using-bottle-py-in-production/